# How to use the after parameter on spotify's API for current_user_recently_played?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

Currently working on a mini project and I'm trying to get a list of songs that I was listening to a week ago but for some reason it only displays the last 50 songs I listened to. I've tried using the after parameter for the current_user_recently_played but it still only displays the last 50.

```
today = datetime.now()
    last_7_days = today - timedelta(days=7)
    last_7_days_unix_timestamp = int(last_7_days.timestamp()) * 1000 # finds the unix timestamp from a week ago
#create a spotify object called spobj, trying to grab the last 50 songs from a week ago
    results = spobj.current_user_recently_played(limit = 50, after=last_7_days_unix_timestamp, before = None)

    if "items" in results:
        for item in results["items"]:
            track_name = item["track"]["name"]
            artist_name = item["track"]["artists"][0]["name"]
            print(f"Song: {track_name} - Artist: {artist_name}")
    else:
        print("No recently played songs found.")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The limit is the last 50, regardless of the timestamp.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that the problem is the list of 50 songs is not from a week ago even though I need the 50 from one week ago.

Comment: In other words, the timestamp does nothing. You can only get **the last** 50 tracks you've listened to.

Comment: Hmm I see I guess im confused, since I thought the documentation stated that I can use the timestamp as a cursor and it's one of the parameters, I guess i was reading the documentation wrong?

Comment: The output does change if you fill in a different limit bellow 50 and a value for *before* or/and *after*, but it would still return a subset of the last 50 recently played tracks.

Comment: That's what im saying i'm inputing a value for after but I don't think the timestamp is working is what i'm struggling with

Comment: A subset of 50 of the last 50 recently played tracks doesn't change if you change the timestamp.